# Is there way bevel inside corner?

Tags: bevel

Trying to bevel inside corner without adding extra edges.

[image]
[image]

Is there a better way bevel corner without adding extra edges? On the example below having extra edges is not a problem but some other situation needed to have fewer edges as possible. Trying to avoid Ngon.
[image]

Comment: https://topologyguides.com/post/126426510380/sub-d-corner-types-click-to-see-high-res